# Trying to get sticky bar to hover abouve footer on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Been trying for ages to get this to work. The div 'scroller' sticks on scroll but it rolls over the footer when scrolling to the very bottom. Is there a way to make it hover above the footer when it gets to that point?

My code as follows:

HTML

```
<div id="scroller-anchor"></div> 
    <div id="scroller">
        <div class="sidebar-nav">
            <a href="#"><span>Next</span></a>
            <a href="#"><span><br/>Prev</span></a>
            <a href="#"><span>back</span></a>
        </div>
    </div> 
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<footer></footer>
```

CSS

```
.sidebar-nav{ height: 200px; background: yellow; }
footer { height: 600px; background: black; display: block; }
```

JQUERY:

```
function moveScroller() {
    var $anchor = $("#scroller-anchor");
    var $scroller = $('#scroller'); 

    var move = function() {

        var st = $(window).scrollTop();
        var ot = $anchor.offset().top;

        if(st > ot) {
            $scroller.css({
                position: "fixed",
                top: "0px"
            });
        } else {
            if(st <= ot) {
                $scroller.css({
                    position: "relative",
                    top: ""
                });
            }
        }
    };
    $(window).scroll(move);
    move(); 
}

$(function() {
   moveScroller();
});
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/xxfairydragonxx/r90rb4gf/

Tried variety of methods including adding a css value that gives a negative margin to the 'scroller' div when reaching a certain point but alas I cant seem to come up with a working solution.

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

```js
function moveScroller() {
    var $anchor = $("#scroller-anchor");
    var $scroller = $('#scroller');
    var move = function() {
        var st = $(window).scrollTop();
        var ot = $anchor.offset().top;
        var scroller_Height =  $scroller.outerHeight(true);
      var footer_top = $('#footer').offset().top - scroller_Height;
        if(st < footer_top){
          if(st > ot && st < footer_top) {
              $scroller.css({
                  position: "fixed",
                  top: "0px"
              });
          } else {
            $scroller.css({
              position: "relative",
              top : "0px"
            });
          }
        }else{
          $scroller.css({
              position: "absolute",
              top : "0px"
            });
        }
    };
    $(window).scroll(move);
    move(); 
}

$(function() {
       moveScroller();
});
```

```css
.sidebar-nav{ height: 200px; background: yellow; }
footer { height: 600px; background: black; display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="scroller-anchor"></div> 
        <div id="scroller">
            <div class="sidebar-nav">
                <a href="#"><span>Next</span></a>
                <a href="#"><span><br/>Prev</span></a>
                <a href="#"><span>back</span></a>
            </div>
        </div> 
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<footer id="footer"></footer>
```

**Steps:**

1- You need to get the `offset().top` for footer and decrease it with `#scroller` height *when top of footer touch the bottom of scroller do the action*

2- Use `if(st > ot && st < footer_top)` instead of `if(st > ot)` **BUT** if not `(st > ot && st < footer_top)` your `#scroller` back to `relative` which change again the footer `offset().top` so it'll be confused between `fixed` and `relative` positions .. so you need to make another `if(st < footer_top){` and change the `#scroller` position to `absolute` instead of `relative` to keep the code read the footer `offset().top` in a right way

3- By using `var ot = $anchor.offset().top;` it will always return 0 so no need to define it and change `ot` with 0

4- If you need your `#scroller` position will be `fixed` after the scroll it bigger than the height of the `#scroller` then you can use `scroller_Height` instead of `ot`